# How to use NHibernate CurrentSessionContext within a Timer

Tags: .net, nhibernate, session

I build a repository class that use `ISessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()` to find the current session that its methods should work with and used `CurrentSessionContext.Bind` to bind a session within my application. Inside the NHibernate config I used `thread_static` as my `current_session_context_class`.

This worked perfectly so far. On each thread I created a new session that will be used by the repository instance.

But when I use a `System.Threading.Timer` the callback will be called on any thread within the ThreadPool. So that I can't bind a session beyond the execution of one callback, because the next callback could be executed on a different thread.

How should sessions be handled (with or without `CurrentSessionContext`) within a `System.Threading.Timer` if one session should be used on two or more executions of the callback?

Comment: Why do you need to use the same session for more then one callback request?

Comment: Because my application is running in the background and will wait a certain amount of time between each action (database insert and file copy) in order to prevent the system from overloading. The session will only be disposed if everything is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A session should be tied to a unit of work.  It sounds like you just need a new session on every call back. Sessions are very light weight to create.